# Why would a registered NIB fail to dequeue?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

In my app, I do the following in my setup:

```
let dataCell = UINib(nibName: kData, bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
collectionView.registerNib(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: ALBTableViewCellType.Data.rawValue)
```

I verified dataCell is not nil.

Then as part of my collectionView, I have this call:

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(ALBTableViewCellType.Data.rawValue, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell
```

However, as this dequeue is called, I get an error:
 `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle:...`

Why won't a registered NIB dequeue?  Just to verify, I tried removing the `as! UICollectionViewCell` and casting it later, but that isn't the issue. It still crashes on the same line with the same error.

Comment: which version of Xcode are you using ?

Comment: @matt kData is a string that gives the name of the XIB file. I have a few that I'm trying to register.

Comment: @Aladin Xcode version 6.4

Comment: @AaronBratcher But I'm asking you to prove it, don't you see? Log `kData`. Show a screen shot of your xib file in the project navigator. - Oh, and show us the rest of that error message; it tells exactly what the problem is, so it's no help to us if you conceal it!

Comment: @matt  Good call, the string I was using for the constant `kData` had a misspelling so the NIB file it was supposed to be reflecting was inaccurate. Interestingly, the let dataCell = UINIB call wasn't failing as I thought it would.

Comment: "the string I was using had a misspelling" That is what I meant by "there is no such nib" in my answer.

Comment: "the let dataCell = UINIB call wasn't failing" Oh, yes - it _was_ failing, but _you_ were not checking to see _whether_ it had failed.

Answer (score 0):

You are not giving anywhere near enough information, but basically there are two main possibilities:

- There is no such nib as the nib you have registered with the table view.
- There is such a nib, but it is incorrectly constructed - it must contain exactly *one* top-level object, and that object must be a table cell.